# jQuery doesn't load unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I'm using the following code to set the layout of my page as I don't see a way to do it by using CSS. Trouble is - it works fine when the page loads (or is being refreshed), but if I navigate to the page where the necesserry elements are located at using links on the page, it doesn't work. Why is that and what could I do to fix it? Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('article:not(:nth-child(4n))').css('margin-right', '20px');
});
```

Comment: Is there an address so we can see it live?

Comment: Why cannot you just use a CSS rule?

Comment: Maybe you got something else modifying articles margin when you scroll to or focus an element.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot show it to you live yet. @A.Wolff how would you suggest doing that with CSS?

Comment: Ensure you code its execute use console.log() inside $(document).ready

Comment: Are you loading something with AJAX?

Comment: @Xeen `article:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
    margin-right:20px;
}`  And if you don't have any live link, at least, provide a jsfiddle which replicate your issue

Comment: do it like A.Wolff said, btw. the problem seems to be that you navigate to a different page, is your <script> loaded there also?